# Rename URL while opening in New tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services

I have application , in which while button click event i am trying to open SSRS report on new tab.\
Below is my code used.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('" + SSRSURL + "','_newtab');", true);
```

If my SSRSURL is www.google.com for example, i want to open it in new tab with my URL as Report.
Basically i just want to rename URL while opening it in new tab.

can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want SSRSURL to be the current page (as per your Google example) then

```
window.open('" + document.URL + "','_newtab');
```

just an FYI, as far as I know it is impossible to force a new tab, it all depends on the users browser setup, or the function of the browser.

if you mean you want to go to google.com with something after it then adjust code as needed

```
window.open('http://www.google.com?" + document.URL + "','_newtab');
```

Comment: ok. But there is concept called URL ReWriting.. What is that? it is used for renaming URL right.

Comment: URL rewriting is a server thing not javascript, http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/
and also